# iterate over lines in file then find in directory

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am having trouble looping and searching. It seems that the loop is not waiting for the find to finish. What am I doing wrong?

I made a loop the reads a file line by line. I then want to use that "name" to search a directory looking to see if a folder has that name. If it exists copy it to a drive.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRFIND="$2"
DIRCOPY="$3"

if [ -d $DIRFIND ]; then

    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        echo "$line"

        FILE=`find "$DIRFIND" -type d -name "$line"`

        if [ -n "$FILE" ]; then
            echo "Found $FILE"
            cp -a "$FILE" "$DIRCOPY"
        else
            echo "$line not found."
        fi

    done < "$1"
else
    echo "No such file or directory"
fi
```

Comment: You want to find files with your `find` command so: ` FILE=`find "$DIRFIND" -type f -name "$line"``

Comment: What's `$DIR`? How is that different from `$DIRFIND`? Is the issue that you have `-type d` but you meant `-type f` as JNevill indicated?

Comment: @Toadman30 How do you want to call the script? i.e. test.sh $DIRFIND $DIRCOPY? The if [ -d $DIR ] seems to be an issue as $DIR is not defined.

Comment: Sorry that is a typo. It should be $DIRFIND. I call it by ./find_dir.sh then three arguments. No, I am not trying to find files, I am trying to find directories with that filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried xargs...

### Proposed Solution

```
cat filenamelist | xargs -n1 -I {} find . -type d -name {} -print | xargs -n1 -I {} mv {} .
```

what the above does is pipe a list of filenames into find (one at a time), when found `find` prints the name and passes to `xarg` which moves the file...

### Expansion

file = yogo

```
yogo -> | xargs -n1 -I yogo find . -type d -name yogo -print | xargs -n1 -I {} mv ./<path>/yogo .
```

I hope the above helps, note that `xargs` has the advantage that you do not run out of command line buffer.